# Raspberry pi 4 Hostname always changing

Tags: linux, pi-4, raspbian-buster, docker, mqtt

I have a raspberry pi 4 with raspbian buster installed. I set the hostname using raspi-config to "myrpi". I can connect to it using ssh and it works fine. But after a few hours or so, the hostname changes to "myrpi-3" where 3 can be any number. The greatest number I got so far was 13. I know it changes because I scan my network using Advanced IP Scanner and it still shows the same IP address. I have no idea what is happening. I am running a mqtt broker, a postgresql database and a web server using docker.

I fix this by rebooting and it goes back to "myrpi" but after few hours, it changes to another hostname, example "myrpi-5".

Anyone experienced this before or knows what is happening and how to prevent the frequent change in hostname?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is the output of `cat /etc/hostname` ?

Comment: `cat /etc/hostname`
myrpi

Comment: Wifi or ethernet? Have you set up dhcp reservation on your router?

Comment: I tried both even at the same time. Using Advanced IP Scanner, they both have the same hostname but different IPs. I didn't touch my router settings because I've had other pi's in my network but didn't have this problem

Comment: "I've had other pi's in my network " - they aren't all called 'myrpi' by any chance?

Comment: Of course that would cause problems but no